# Content remains hovered when sub content is opened

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use the following simple jQuery `slideToggle` to slide in contents and subcontents.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}


.button:hover, .content:hover {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
Open Content
</div>
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="content"> content 1 </div>
  <div class="content"> content 2 </div>
  <div class ="button"> content 3 </div>
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="content"> content 3a </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3b </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3c </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3d </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
```

You can also find all the code in the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mgpqhf4k/8/). 
All this works fine so far.

---

Now as you can see in my code I hover the content in `blue` when the cursor goes over a certain element. My target is now that when the user opens the panel below `content 3` that the `<div>` of `content 3` remains hovered in `blue` as long as the user navigates with the cursor in `content 3a, 3b, 3c, 3d`.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}


.button:hover, .content:hover {
 background: blue;
}
.active {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
Open Content
</div>
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="content"> content 1 </div>
  <div class="content"> content 2 </div>
  <div class ="button"> content 3 </div>
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="content"> content 3a </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3b </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3c </div>
    <div class="content"> content 3d </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Active CSS Selector

You needed to add the [active](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) CSS selector

```
.active {
 background: #2b5eae;
 color:#fff;
}
```

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
body {padding:20px;}
section {
width:300px;
border: 1px solid #555;
overflow:hidden;
padding:10px 15px;
}
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}
.button {
padding:10px 15px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
.content, .button {border-radius:4px;}
.content {padding:5px 12px;}
.button:hover, .content:hover {
 background: #2b5eae;
 color:#fff;
}
.active {
 background: #2b5eae;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<section>
<div class="button">
Open Content
</div>
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="content"> Content 1 </div>
  <div class="content"> Content 2 </div>
  <div class ="button"> Open Content 2 </div>
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="content"> Content 3a </div>
  <div class="content"> Content 3b </div>
  <div class="content"> Content 3c </div>
  <div class="content"> Content 3d </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
```